# How do I update AppxPackage in C# DISM API?

Tags: c#, .net, dism

I want to update AppxPackage with appxmanifest.xml with C# DISM API.

This is how I do it in powershell :

```
Dism /Online /Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "C\Program Files\WindowsApp\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1805.1201.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml
```

Is it possible to do the same in C#? I don't want to just run the powershell command in C#.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Dism

Comment: I use Microsoft.Dism yes but I don't know how to update AppxPackage